# How to show more decimals when print p values using scipy.stats.t.sf

Tags: python, scipy, p-value

I am trying to print p-value using the z-score, `z`, and number of observations, `N`.

```py
import scipy

z = 17.14275973
N = 8960
p = scipy.stats.t.sf(abs(z), df=N-1,)*2
print(p)
[0.]
```

I want it to show more decimals such as `0.00000`.
I have tried to use `np.round` but it still only gives the same results.

```py
p = np.round(scipy.stats.t.sf(abs(z), df=N-1,)*2, 5)
print(p)
[0.]
```

I have tried to use `format` it does give me more decimals but I do not want to print strings, and I doubt it shows the actual p-value but just read it as `0` and print `0.00000`.

Comment: Welcome.. what is `z` and `N`?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the formatting of the output when printing using f-strings as follows:

```py
import scipy.stats
z = 17.14275973
N = 8960

# Calculate the p-value
p = scipy.stats.t.sf(abs(z), df=N-1) * 2

# Print with formatting
print(f"{p}")
```

the output would be in scientific format

```bash
7.650583391648916e-65
```

BTW, everything you give the `print()` function is converted to strings according to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream, separated by sep and followed by end.

Comment: Thanks! When I have larger z score such as `58`, it still gives me `0.0`. Is there a way to solve this with large z score, or perhaps it is `0` that I don't need to worry about interpreting significance from that.

Comment: It's actually so close to zero I don't believe the floating point number in python can capture it, even with scientific notation with 100 decimal points, it's still 0
```print(f"{p:.100E}")  # also zero```